# Beginner async/await question for api requests

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio

I want speed up some API requests... for that I try to figure out how to do and copy some code which run but when I try my own code its no longer asynchrone. Maybe someone find the fail?

Copy Code (guess from stackoverflow):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def func_normal():
    print('A')
    yield from asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('B')
    return 'saad'

@asyncio.coroutine
def func_infinite():
    for i in range(10):
        print("--%d" % i)
    return 'saad2'

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = func_normal(), func_infinite()
a, b = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
print("func_normal()={a}, func_infinite()={b}".format(**vars()))
loop.close()
```

My "own" code (I need at the end a list returned and merge the results of all functions):

```
import asyncio
import time


@asyncio.coroutine
def say_after(start,count,say,yep=True):
    retl = []
    if yep:
        time.sleep(5)
    for x in range(start,count):
        retl.append(x)
        print(say)
    return retl


def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
        
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = say_after(10,20,"a"), say_after(20,30,"b",False)
    a, b = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    print("func_normal()={a}, func_infinite()={b}".format(**vars()))
    loop.close()
    c =  a + b

    #print(c)
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

main()
```

Or  I m completly wrong and should solve that with multithreading? What would be the best way for API requests that returns a list that I need to merge?

Comment: Your code needs one or more points where the execution is handed back to the event loop for execution of something else to be asynchronous. This is what the "yield from" in first code is for ("await" in newer Python versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added comment for each section that needs improvement. Removed some to simply code.

In fact, I didn't find any performance uplift with using `range()` wrapped in coroutine and using `async def`, might worth with heavier operations.

```
import asyncio
import time

# @asyncio.coroutine IS DEPRECATED since python 3.8
@asyncio.coroutine
def say_after(wait=True):
    result = []

    if wait:
        print("I'm sleeping!")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("'morning!")
        # This BLOCKs thread, but release GIL so other thread can run.
        # But asyncio runs in ONE thread, so this still harms simultaneity.

    # normal for is BLOCKING operation.
    for i in range(5):
        result.append(i)
        print(i, end='')
    print()

    return result


def main():
    start = time.time()

    # Loop argument will be DEPRECATED from python 3.10
    # Make main() as coroutine, then use asyncio.run(main()).
    # It will be in asyncio Event loop, without explicitly passing Loop.
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = say_after(), say_after(False)

    # As we will use asyncio.run(main()) from now on, this should be await-ed.
    a, b = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

    print(f"Took {time.time() - start:5f}")

    loop.close()


main()
```

Better way:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def say_after(wait=True):
    result = []

    if wait:
        print("I'm sleeping!")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  # 'await' a coroutine version of it instead.
        print("'morning!")

    # wrap iterator in generator - or coroutine
    async def asynchronous_range(end):
        for _i in range(end):
            yield _i

    # use it with async for
    async for i in asynchronous_range(5):
        result.append(i)
        print(i, end='')
    print()

    return result


async def main():
    start = time.time()

    tasks = say_after(), say_after(False)
    a, b = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    print(f"Took {time.time() - start:5f}")


asyncio.run(main())
```

---

#### Result

Your code:

```
DeprecationWarning: "@coroutine" decorator is deprecated since Python 3.8, use "async def" instead
  def say_after(wait=True):
I'm sleeping!
'morning!
01234
01234
Took 5.003802
```

Better async code:

```
I'm sleeping!
01234
'morning!
01234
Took 2.013863
```

Note that fixed code now finish it's job while other task is sleeping.

Comment: Maybe wrapping ```for``` in coroutine is not worth at all - I'll check it.